# How I can convert file with any format to text format using Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, text-extraction

I am trying to have a converter that can convert any file of any format to text, so that processing becomes easier to me. I have used the Python `textract` library.
Here is the documentation:  https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I have install it using the `pip` and have tried to use it. But got error and could not understand how to resolve it.

```
>>> import textract
>>> text = textract.process('C:\Users\beta\Desktop\Projects Done With Specification.pdf', method='pdfminer')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Even I have tried using the command without specifying method.

```
>>> import textract
>>> text = textract.process('C:\Users\beta\Desktop\Projects Done With Specification.pdf')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Kindly let me know how I can get rid of this issue with your suggestion. If it is possible then please suggest me the solution, if there is anything else that can be handy instead of `textract`, then still you can suggest me. I would like to hear.

Comment: So you want to extract all strings from a file, like the [strings](http://www.linfo.org/strings.html) command in unix?

Answer (score 2):

The `\` character means different things in different contexts. In Windows pathnames, it is the directory separator. In Python strings, it introduces escape sequences. When specifying paths, you have to account for this.

Try any one of these:

```
text = textract.process('C:\\Users\\beta\\Desktop\\Projects Done With Specification.pdf', method='pdfminer')
text = textract.process(r'C:\Users\beta\Desktop\Projects Done With Specification.pdf', method='pdfminer')
text = textract.process('C:/Users/beta/Desktop/Projects Done With Specification.pdf', method='pdfminer')
```

Comment: I get this after using your solution. https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/6f595c61f08c80081a57c527144c191b

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the string

```
'C:\Users\beta\Desktop\Projects Done With Specification.pdf'
```

The \U starts an eight-character Unicode escape, such as '\U00014321`. In your code, the escape is followed by the character 's', which is invalid.

You either need to duplicate all backslashes, or prefix the string with r (to produce a raw string).

Comment: Sorry but it didn't worked: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/6f595c61f08c80081a57c527144c191b

Comment: @JafferWilson Then the problem is probably that you have spaces in your file name. Try renaming the file to "Projects_Done_With_Specification.pdf" and update the path in your code to: "C:\Users\beta\Desktop\Projects_Done_With_Specification.pdf"

Comment: I tried to remove the spaces and the run the program .. got new issue: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/59e0602f62751c96aba91d7047f322ed

Comment: @JafferWilson The first error occurred at pdf_parser.py", line 31. The second error occurred at pdf_parser.py", line 20. Is there a chance you have another file path specified besides the first one?

Comment: not it is the same file. As you have said that removing spaces from the file name may help so I tried with removing the spaces from the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try `encoding='utf-8'`

```
textract.process('C:\Users\beta\Desktop\Projects Done With Specification.pdf', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, error is due to invalid path. 
Try this and it works:
'C:\Users\beta\Desktop\Projects Done With Specification.pdf' 
                               "OR"
'C:/Users/beta/Desktop/Projects Done With Specification.pdf'

Answer (score 0):

```
import textract
text = textract.process(r'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\doc\an.docx', encoding='utf-8')
```

this worked for me. Try.

Comment: Thank you for your contribute. However, this answer, while good, was already provided in 2017. Please avoid posting duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

`textract` doesn't work for me, when I was trying to convert `slurm` file output to `text` file. But simple `with open` did.

```py
with open('disktest.o1761955', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
```